# Footballers with most free kicks scored

Tags: football, trivia, records

Who are the footballers with most free kicks scored? We all remember Juninho Pernambucano, but who else?

Comment: From your posts it seems that you are interested in various statistics and trivia. If you find something interesting, feel free to post such stuff also in [Sports News chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/29021/sports-news). See the beginning of the transcript for an explanation [what is the intended purpose of this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/29021/2015/9/11), (In chat you can post things which would not be a good fit for a question on the main site, but are still interesting for sports fans.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

| # | Player | Goals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juninho Pernambucano | 77 |
| 2 | Pelé | 70 |
| 3 | Víctor Legrotaglie | 66 |
| 3 | Ronaldinho Gaúcho | 66 |
| **5** | **Lionel Messi** | **65** |
| 5 | David Beckham | 65 |
| 7 | Diego Armando Maradona | 62 |
| 7 | Zico | 62 |
| **9** | **Cristiano Ronaldo** | **60** |
| 9 | Ronald Koeman | 60 |
| 10 | Rogério Ceni | 59 |
| 10 | Marcelinho Carioca | 59 |
| 13 | Kostas Frantzeskos | 57 |

*Last update: 8 September 2023*

Sources:

- [Sport](https://www.sport-english.com/en/news/barca/the-free-kick-record-lionel-messi-may-never-beat-6745078) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190602141912/https://www.sport-english.com/en/news/barca/the-free-kick-record-lionel-messi-may-never-beat-6745078))
- [Messi Stats](https://messi.starplayerstats.com/en/goals/0/0/all/0/0/0/t/f/all/0/0/1)